# Swift - crash on if let

Tags: swift

I try to work with push notifications - I monitor for variable in payload, and if it exists, I perform my stuff. This works good, but the problems is that if I dont have variable I get app crash even if I use `if let` binding.

method looks like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if let key : String = userInfo["custom"]!["a"]!!["d"] as! String  {
        print("key was received")
    }
    completionHandler(.NewData)
}
```

If key exist in userData everything is fine. But if it isn't - app crashes. How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are coding that there is definitely the key in the userInfo dictionary, you need to use ? to query if it is, otherwise it will crash when the key is not there and you try use your nil key variable.

```
if let key : String = userInfo["custom"]?["a"]??["d"] as? String  {
    print("key was received")
}
```

The concept of optionals is to avoid that very issue, of accessing nil objects at runtime. So if let someObject = something as? someType helps to protect against this. So it is helpful for dynamic data that is out of the programs control, e.g. JSON responses.

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks a lot!